What's the difference between Calibrite "ColorChecker Display" and "Display SL"
As far as I know the "ColorChecker Display" is the older model and the "Display SL" is the current one. The technical specifications on the homepage just give information about the hardware requirements for the computer but there are no technical details about the device itself.
Can anyone tell me if there is a significant improvement on the newer model?

The confusion that band creates on their own products, is a good reason to explore DataColor :S

The SL is more sensitive, but it is still not particularly well suited for higher contrast modern displays (limited to 1000 nits).
